# How are document fields indexed in parse-server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Are they ALL indexed by default? Should I index them? If so, how? By directly talking to mongodb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use parse-server you must maintain the DB indexes on your own.

Parse.com did it for you but since parse.com shut down their service and open source it (parse-server) you need to maintain the indexes on your own.

You have multiple options to create indexes in MongoDB:

1. via MongoDB shell
2. via MongoDB client tools (e.g. [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/lp/compass?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=EMEA_Israel_CorpEntOnly_Brand_Beta_FM&utm_keyword=%2Bcompass%20%2Bmongodb&utm_device=c&utm_network=g&utm_medium=cpc&utm_creative=187932930457&utm_matchtype=b&_bt=187932930457&_bk=%2Bcompass%20%2Bmongodb&_bm=b&_bn=g&jmp=search&gclid=COywleeL4NMCFSex7Qod9IgAdQ), [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) etc.)
3. via code

The must easiest option is 2